# How can I convert the input __NSArrayM into an AppleScript list in an Automator Action project?

Tags: applescript, automator, applescript-objc

## Automator Action

I am making a custom Automator action for manipulating text input. I tested the input to see what class it was and the result was `__NSArrayM`. This means that I need to somehow convert this input into a list that AppleScript can understand—and eventually to a string. I just need to isolate the string and then convert it back to the same object for the output.

Summary:

- Convert the __NSArrayM **input** to an AppleScript list object
- Convert AppleScript list object back to a __NSArrayM for the **output**

I would like my automator to look something like this:
[image]

## Coding Attempt in XCode

My attempt at coding this looks like:

```
script Change_Case
    property parent : class "AMBundleAction"
    property menuChoices : {"Title Case","UPPER CASE","lower case","tOGGLE cASE"}
    property menuSelection : 0
    on runWithInput_fromAction_error_(input, anAction, errorRef)
        set inputClass to class of input -- just for debugging

        set menuSel to menuSelection
        if menuSel is 0 -- Title Case
            display dialog menuSel as string
        end if

        tell class "NSArray" of current application to set inputValues to arrayWithObjects_(input)
        log inputValues -- just for debugging
    end runWithInput_fromAction_error_
end script
```

---

## Final Code Update

I thought I would post the final code to my automator action for completeness. The key step was to make the input and output `com.apple.cocoa.string`as shown in the picture below.

```
script Change_Case
    property parent : class "AMBundleAction"
    property menuChoices : {"Title Case","UPPER CASE","lower case","tOGGLE cASE"}
    property menuSelection : missing value
    property array : class "NSArray"
    
    on runWithInput_fromAction_error_(input, anAction, errorRef)
        set inputValues to input as list
        set theString to item 1 of inputValues

        if (menuSelection as string) is "missing value"
            set menuSelection to 0
        end if
        set menuSelection to menuSelection as integer
        
        if menuSelection is 0 -- Title Case
            --display dialog "Title Case, Menu Selection ID: " & menuSelection as string
            set mycode to "import sys; print sys.argv[1].title()"
            set myscript to "/usr/bin/python -c " & mycode's quoted form & " " & quoted form of theString
            set output to (do shell script myscript) as string
        end if
        if menuSelection is 1 -- UPPER CASE
            --display dialog "Upper Case, Menu Selection ID: " & menuSelection as string
            set mycode to "import sys; print sys.argv[1].upper()"
            set myscript to "/usr/bin/python -c " & mycode's quoted form & " " & quoted form of theString
            set output to (do shell script myscript) as string
        end if
        if menuSelection is 2 -- lower case
            --display dialog "Lower Case, Menu Selection ID: " & menuSelection as string
            set mycode to "import sys; print sys.argv[1].lower()"
            set myscript to "/usr/bin/python -c " & mycode's quoted form & " " & quoted form of theString
            set output to (do shell script myscript) as string
        end if
        if menuSelection is 3 -- tOGGLE cASE
            --display dialog "Swap Case, Menu Selection ID: " & menuSelection as string
            set mycode to "import sys; print sys.argv[1].swapcase()"
            set myscript to "/usr/bin/python -c " & mycode's quoted form & " " & quoted form of theString
            set output to (do shell script myscript) as string
        end if
        return output
    end runWithInput_fromAction_error_
end script
```

[image: inputautomator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the goal of the script to take an array of text strings, and change their case based upon the menuSelection?

You can coerce the passed array to an AS list:

```
set inputValues to input as list
```

Is it mostly planned to receive a single text input? Then go to Target/General, Input and Output options:
com.apple.applescript.text-object
or
com.apple.cocoa.string
These would be the class of the array items passed.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly and yes, it will most likely receive only a single text input, but it would also be cool if it could handle multiple inputs for flexibility purposes. I think I tried this and it wasn't working. I thought I would need a Cocoa method.

Comment: The missing ingredient was to put com.apple.applescript.text-object or com.apple.cocoa.string into the "Input types accepted by the Automator Action" area (using XCode 5.1.1) under General. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's working for you. Hard to find help on creating automator actions, so glad to pass this bit of knowledge on to another. (I've still got an active Automator Action question unanswered on stack.)

Comment: Yes, I know there is hardly anything up to date! Even Shane Stanley doesn't create  Automator actions. May I suggest linking to your unanswered question next time. I will do it for you this time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920160/save-a-user-popup-selection-in-a-custom-automator-action